# How can I get the Order of the Testcase in a Suite programmatically using TFS API

Tags: testcase, microsoft-test-manager, tfs-sdk

I'm using TFS API to create a custom tool for my company. 
I ran to an issue that I need to display the test cases in a suite by their order in Test Manager ( not the ID one).
I search the IStaticTestSuite interface, and ITestCase interface but it I can't find where they store the Test case order.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you find any way to achieve this? I am also struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but it can help others with the same issue...

Use:
staticSuite.SubSuites.OrderBy(s => s.Title)

In this case it is ordering by Title.

Comment: Well, it's not really what I'm asking for. I mean, how can I get the Order property of testcases in a Suite as described in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997699.aspx. I want to order testcases by their Order defined in Test Manager (not by Title, or other attributes)

Comment: Oh, i get it! Let me get some things done and i'll give it a look